# the data is sent without pushing the button in my form in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, forms

Hello I made a form in php with db in mysql and when I use it works but when I reload the page send the data I send previously and the records are duplicated please can you help me?

some images:
[that's how the form looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndRmM.png)

this is the code:
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38BTj.png)

Comment: In the future please post code, not images.

Comment: try to post the code but received a notification where it said that it was more code than the description

Comment: That would mean you were including too much code. The code provided should also be in a minimal, just enough to produce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Send 303 code on the same page to the client after first submit, client won't be able to submit it again with "reload" button.

```php
header("Location: $url", true, 303); die; # where $url is your page
```

Comment: Is that the connection string?

Comment: @douglas, not sure what you are talking about.

Comment: this is my connection string:                                                                  <?php 
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","fastjuice")or die("Error");
 ?>

Comment: @douglas nope, it's HTTP header builder. Code above redirects client to another page (or same page) with a help of HTTP 303 code to clean submitted data from client's side. You have to place it in the end of your main logic, e.g. after your last mysql insert.

Comment: $url="reserva.php";
header("Location: $url", true,303); die; // it's okay ?  now in firefox I get a message "The page isn’t redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

    This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies."

Comment: @douglas add a hidden field (```<input type="hidden" name="sumbit" value="1">```) in your form, and insert ```header("Location: ...")``` into the ```if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) { ... }``` statement to prevent endless redirect from the same page to the same page.

Comment: Try but stay the same :(

Comment: @douglas no code - no ideas what did you wrong

Comment: Thank you! now it works for me just had to put it inside the code but now does not run the confirmation script e.e